# Playwright POST Request Error: 'Required request body is missing

Tags: spring-boot, rest, post, playwright

I'm encountering an issue with Playwright while sending a POST request using the `request.post()` method. However, when I send the same request using Postman, I receive the response correctly.

Here's the error message I'm receiving:

Response:

```
 {
  "message" : "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.scd.model.User>)",
  "errorCode" : "BAD_REQUEST",
  "validationErrors" : [ ]
}
```

Playwright code:

```js
test("POST Create Post request", async ({ request }) => {
    const raw = JSON.stringify({
        "iban": "DE8123456781234567898",
        "creditor": "",
        "accountHolder": "Max Miller",
        "signatureDate": "2024-02-21T06:21:57.306Z",
        "signatureLocation": "Reynoldston",
    });

    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',           
    };

    const createPostRequestUrl = 'https://test.system.companyname.io/service/v1/872f774d-12d34-67jj4-abcde-4566743450/mandate';

    // Make the actual request
    const response = await request.post(createPostRequestUrl, {
        headers: headers,
        body: raw
    });

    // Process the response
    const responseBody = await response.text();
    console.log(responseBody);
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: A 400 Bad Request can indicate that perhaps the route you're trying to hit isn't formed correctly or that there could be something wrong with your payload.   You're reaching the service successfully.

Comment: @Anton I think that's the question--why is the body considered missing in the Playwright version, and not in the Postman version? And how to fix. OP, can you provide a sample backend that reproduces the problem? This code seems fine to me so having something to run would be useful. Can you repro with https://httpbin.org/post, for example?

Comment: The payload in postman and in playwright is same (JSON) I am not sure where it is going wrong, even the curl request extracted from postman works fine... Any pointers how can I check payload?

Comment: Instead of, "body: raw" shouldn't it be, "data: raw"?   I don't see any, "body" property on the post method for request.  Also, I don't think you need to JSON.stringify() it.  Just pass in a regular object.

Comment: @Anton last comment looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 0):

As of Playwright version 1.42.1 the documentation states that the payload should be using the, "data" property.

https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing

```
test('should create a bug report', async ({ request }) => {
  const newIssue = await request.post(`/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/issues`, {
    data: {
      title: '[Bug] report 1',
      body: 'Bug description',
    }
  });
  expect(newIssue.ok()).toBeTruthy();

  const issues = await request.get(`/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/issues`);
  expect(issues.ok()).toBeTruthy();
  expect(await issues.json()).toContainEqual(expect.objectContaining({
    title: '[Bug] report 1',
    body: 'Bug description'
  }));
});
```

That is a direct quote from the documentation but you can see the data property being used.  Not a, "body" property.

I hope this answer helps anyone that finds themselves here.

Looking at the original post, this is what I would do:

```
test("POST Create Post request", async ({ request }) => {
    const raw = {
        iban: 'DE8123456781234567898',
        creditor: '',
        accountHolder: 'Max Miller',
        signatureDate: '2024-02-21T06:21:57.306Z',
        signatureLocation: 'Reynoldston',
    };

    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',           
    };

    const createPostRequestUrl = 'https://test.system.companyname.io/service/v1/872f774d-12d34-67jj4-abcde-4566743450/mandate';

    // Make the actual request
    const response = await request.post(createPostRequestUrl, {
        data: raw,
        headers: headers,
    });

    // Process the response
    const responseBody = await response.text();
    console.log(responseBody);
});
```